# Ubuntu Software does not load updates

Tags: 16.04, updates

When I open `Ubuntu Software`, it shows me that there are some updates which have to be done. But after clicking them for several times, the installation process just doesn't work. I also tried to restart.

[image]

If I use the `Software Updater` it tells me this message:

[image]

If I click `OK`, the update ends. If I click `settings` all options are checked:

[image]

This whole update process was really not user friendly developed. Do you know what can be done else? I also tried the `terminal` `sudo apt update` `sudo apt upgrade`, there are still undone updates in the Software Center and the Software Updater!

The output of the terminal is:

```
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
E: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

PS: Who has marked this as duplicate? The so called duplicate is about why is Ubuntu Software showing these updates? Should I install them? My question is about how to install them? I can't install them because it doesnt work!

**SOLUTION:**
For me the `terminal`, the `software-center` etc failed, but `Synaptic Package Manger` worked! Even if it makes no sense at all, because all these apps do the same thing. I hope Ubuntu could explain this to me.

Comment: If you are comfortable in a terminal environment, try running `apt clean && apt autoclean`

Comment: Have you been clicking on the "Settings" button on the second screenshot as well? Can you provide more detailed error messages, e.g. from the terminal?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade` ?

Comment: Who has marked this as duplicate? The so called duplicate is about why is Ubuntu Software showing these updates? Should I install them? My question is about how to install them? I can't install them because it doesnt work!

Answer (score 2):

I'd let go of the GUI first.

Open a terminal, e.g. by pressing `CRTL+ALT+T` and then run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure its `CRTL + ALT + T`?

Comment: the GUI still shows me there are updates which have to be done